# Distinguishing regexes from a slash (division) in a JavaScript files with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, buffer

I'm trying to distinguish regexes (/complex regex here/) from division (/) in a JavaScript file by reading it as a buffer in Node.js and walking through the characters one by one. The reason

```
const fs = require('fs');
const buf = fs.readFileSync('sample.js');
const slash = '/'.codePointAt(0);
const backSlash = '\\'.codePointAt(0);
let escaped = false;
for(let key of buf.keys()) {
    if(buf[key] === slash && !escaped) {
        // How do I distinguish this slash? Is it a regex or is it a division sign?
    }
    if(escaped) {
        escaped = false;
    } else if(buf[key] === backSlash) {
        escaped = true; // set escaped to true to ignore the next character.
    }
}
```

There are no comments in the file so I don't have to worry about `//`, `/*`, or `*/`

How should I distinguish between a division sign and a regex?

Comment: It's easier just to use a parser, e.g. Esprima.

Comment: Use a parser library like acorn or esprima; it's not a problem decidable by regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tokenizer feature of [Esprima](http://esprima.org):

```
var esprima = require('esprima');
var tokens = esprima.tokenize('var regex = /foo/bar; var math = 1 / 2');
console.log(tokens);
```

and you'll have the following output:

```
[ { type: 'Keyword', value: 'var' },
  { type: 'Identifier', value: 'regex' },
  { type: 'Punctuator', value: '=' },
  { type: 'RegularExpression',
    value: '/foo/bar',
    regex: { pattern: 'foo', flags: 'bar' } },
  { type: 'Punctuator', value: ';' },
  { type: 'Keyword', value: 'var' },
  { type: 'Identifier', value: 'math' },
  { type: 'Punctuator', value: '=' },
  { type: 'Numeric', value: '1' },
  { type: 'Punctuator', value: '/' },
  { type: 'Numeric', value: '2' } ]
```

As you can see, the tokenizer correctly identifies the first two slashes as part of a regular expression and the last one as the division operator.